# Confluent 5.5.1 Cannot start Kafka Rest, Kafka Server is not running. Error: exit status 127

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Installed and configured Confluent 5.5.1, but unable to >confluent local start
Following are the sequence I did and error I got.

```
root@ubuntu-mini:~/confluent/confluent-5.5.1# confluent local start
    The local commands are intended for a single-node development environment
    only, NOT for production usage. https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html

Using CONFLUENT_CURRENT: /tmp/confluent.ys5Bp70O
zookeeper is already running. Try restarting if needed
Starting kafka
kafka is [UP]
Starting schema-registry
schema-registry is [UP]
Cannot start Kafka Rest, Kafka Server is not running. Check your deployment
Error: exit status 127
root@ubuntu-mini:~/confluent/confluent-5.5.1#
```

Comment: could you share your docker-compose file?

Comment: @Vladimir OP isnt using Docker

Comment: Installed/unzipped package>> set env variables >>  confluent local start >> Error 127

Answer (score 1):

In order to run all Confluent Platform services, you must have around 6-8 GB of RAM available on your machine.

If you don't want all services, then you should start each individually. For example, if you only want Kafka, then `confluent local start kafka` (or `kafka-server-start`)

Note: Read the note, and perhaps use Docker Compose (or Helm) quickstart instructions instead, which more closely will match a production setup.

Comment: OS=Ubuntu26.04 | CPU=2 | RAM=8 Gb |
Also tried to start them one by one, still m getting the same error.

Comment: The error you posted isnt possible with `kafka-server-start`

Comment: @ArpitDave If you are using Ubuntu, I would suggest installing with apt-get https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/deb-ubuntu.html

Comment: I did it by wget package download and configured it. Will try apt-get